# MSSQL перевернуть строки в столбцы

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Ищу способ перевернуть строки в стобцы в MSSQL.
Так выглядит моя таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался сделать так

```
SELECT ta.AuftragID,
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN [Abteilung] = 'Konstruktion' THEN [PlanAufwand]
  END) AS Konstruktion, 
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN [Abteilung] = 'Mechanik' THEN [PlanAufwand]
  END) AS Mechanik,
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN [Abteilung] = 'Verdrahtung' THEN [PlanAufwand]
  END) AS Verdrahtung
FROM Terminliste_Abteilungsablauf ta
```

Однако, из за того, что AuftragID стоит не один раз, получаю что-то вроде этого
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Резуальтат должен выглядить примерно так, может у кого есть решение.

```
AuftragsID Konstruktion Mechanik Verdrahtung
22103776      10            10       10
22103777       5             2       1
```

Пример
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1453280/pivot

Comment: [FROM — использование PIVOT и UNPIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: *Пытался сделать так* Вот прям так, без группировки?

Comment: @Akina группировка не помогает

Comment: *группировка не помогает* Группировка очень даже помогает. Без неё однозначный Syntax error, а с ней (при правильном выражении группировки) хоть какой-то, да результат. Вы выложите данные не фотографиями (мы по ним не лечим), а вменяемо, CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. И требуемый результат покажите именно для этих данных, а не "вот как-то так".

Comment: @Akina https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1453280/pivot так выглядит резуальтаты и то, что я пробовал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использован Dynamic SQL, для того чтобы каждый раз, когда в таблице изменится содержимое, не переписывать PIVOT.

```
drop table if exists #Table1

create table #Table1
(
    AuftragID bigint not null,
    Abteilung nvarchar(200) not null,
    PlanAufwand int
);

insert into #Table1 (AuftragID, Abteilung, PlanAufwand)
values
(22103776, 'bestuck', null),
(22103776, 'cnc', null),
(22103776, 'diverses', null),
(22103776, 'fastlane', null),
(22103776, 'konstruktion', null),
(22103776, 'mechanic', null),
(22103776, 'qualitajdcnoenvowcv', null),
(22103776, 'verdrahtung', null),
(22103777, 'arbeiten', 2),
(22103777, 'bestuck', 2),
(22103777, 'cnc', 5),
(22103777, 'diverses', null),
(22103777, 'fastlane', null),
(22103777, 'konstruktion', 7),
(22103777, 'mechanic', 7),
(22103777, 'qualitajdcnoenvowcv', 2),
(22103777, 'verdrahtung', 3)
--,(22103778, 'NOVOE_ZNACHENIE', 5), 
--(22103776, 'NOVOE_ZNACHENIE', 2),     ---при добавлении новых значений в таблицу, они будут автоматом попадать в запрос с PIVOT'ом
--(22103777, 'NOVOE_ZNACHENIE', null)

declare @val1 nvarchar(max);
declare @val nvarchar(max);
declare @company table ([name] nvarchar(max), num int identity (1,1));
declare @select nvarchar(max);

insert into @company ([name])
select distinct Abteilung as [name] 
from #Table1;


set @val = 
(select stuff((select ',' + [name]
               from @company
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, '')
);


set @val1 = 
(select stuff((select ', isnull(' + [name] + ', ''0'') as '+ [name]
               from @company
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, '')
);


set @select = 'select AuftragID, ' + @val1 +
' from 
    (
        select AuftragID, sum(PlanAufwand) as sumorder, Abteilung as [name]
        from #Table1
        group by AuftragID, Abteilung
    ) t
    pivot(sum(sumorder)
            for [name]
                IN (' + @val + ')
            ) as d';


exec (@select)
```

Comment: спасибо, работает. Маленький вопрос: если данные будут выглядить вот так (AuftragID, Abteilung, PlanAufwand, IstAufwand) (22103777, 'verdrahtung', 3, 6) - как отоброзить такое?

Comment: желательно помечая разницу между первым и второым через Abteilung, т.е mechanicPlan, mechanicIst

Comment: К сожалению в PIVOT агрегирование можно осуществлять только по одному полю. (PlanAufwand). Если вам нужна разница, то без проблем можно внести изменения в агрегирующий элемент: вместо PlanAufwand --> (PlanAufwand - IstAufwand).

Comment: понял, все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш способ:

```sql
SELECT ta.Auftrag,
  MAX( CASE WHEN [Abteilung] = 'Konstruktion' 
            THEN [PlanAufwand]
            END ) AS Konstruktion, 
  MAX( CASE WHEN [Abteilung] = 'Mechanik' 
            THEN [PlanAufwand]
            END ) AS Mechanik,
  MAX( CASE WHEN [Abteilung] = 'Verdrahtung' 
            THEN [PlanAufwand]
            END ) AS Verdrahtung
FROM #yourtable  ta
GROUP BY Auftrag
```

Через сводный запрос:

```sql
SELECT Auftrag, Konstruktion, Mechanik, Verdrahtung
FROM #yourtable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(PlanAufwand) -- может, тут должно быть SUM() ?
    FOR Abteilung IN (Konstruktion, Mechanik, Verdrahtung)
) AS PivotTable;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=48c33fcbf9fb3a9f8e21eca72b27ff67